# Взять атрибут из элемента в xml

Tags: java, xml

Использую `org.dom4j.Document`, в Элементе есть атрибуты, как мне вытащить атрибуты с элемента,

```
<  UFXMsg direction="Rs" msg_type="Application">
```

нужно с элемента `UFXMsg` вытащить значение direction

```
    org.dom4j.Document responseDocument = org.dom4j.DocumentHelper.parseText(value);
    Element element = responseDocument.getRootElement();
```

Comment: Почему не посмотреть доку http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Element.html? Из нее очевидно, что надо воспользоваться методом `Element.attributeValue(String name)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.String attributeValue(QName qName)
```

Возвращает значение атрибута по полному имени или `null`, если атрибут не существует, или пустую строку если атрибут имеет пустое значение.